# How to find the simplest form of integer matrix polynomial?

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, algorithms

For my toy project, related to cellular automata in non-euclidean spaces, I want to find an algorithm that solves the following problem.

Let $M$ is a fixed matrix with characteristic polynomial $p(x)=x^2-3x+1$. 
For example, $M$ could be $\left(\begin{matrix}2&1\\1&1\end{matrix}\right)$.

Let $P$ is a Laurent polynomial in $M$ with integer coefficients:
$$P= \dots + a_2M^2 + a_1M + a_0I + a_{-1}M^{-1} + \dots, a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Define *complexity* of $P$ as the sum of absolute values of its coefficients:
$$C(P) = \sum_i|a_i|$$
**The problem** is: given a specific polynomial $P$ in $M$, find equal with minimal *complexity*.

**Example**: let's $P=3M^0$. It has complexity 3. The simplest equal polynomial is $M+M^{-1}$ of complexity 2, obtained by adding $p(M)M^{-1}$.

My question is: what is (and is there) an algorithm to find the least complex form?

**The problem can be reformulated** like this: given 2-side infinite array of integer numbers $(\dots,a_2,a_1,a_0,a_{-1},\dots)$, where only finite amount of numbers are non-zero, minimize $\sum|a_i|$ by adding or subtracting $(1,-3,1)$ to any 3 consequent numbers.

It is not as trivial as it could seem. At first, I thought that the simple "greedy" algorithm solves the problem: add or subtract (1,-3,1) at all possible locations, until it reduces complexity.

However, it does not!

The simplest example I have is $5M+5M^0$ or (5,5), complexity 10. Application of greedy algorithm produced $2M^2+M+M^0+2M^-1$, or (2,1,1,2), complexity 6. Apparently, there is no way to reduce complexity in one step. However, manual check can show that it is equal to $M^3+M^{-2}$, or (1,0,0,0,0,1) of complexity 2.

Comment: Polynomials where the exponents are allowed to be negative are usually called *Laurent polynomials*. I assume you intend that $M$ is fixed; this isn't clear from your problem description. Usually when we talk about two polynomials being equal we mean their coefficients are equal.

Comment: In which sense are $3M^0$ and $M+M^{-1}$ "equal"?

Comment: @Henning: $M$ is fixed. (See, Dmitry? Told you it wasn't clear!)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes, the matrix M is fixed. I did not mentioned it because I told that its characteristic polynomial is fixed: $p(x)=x^2-3x+1$. The matrix itself is no important, so I did not mentioned it. A sample matrix M is [[2,1],[1,1]]. I'll try to clarify this point, thanks.

Comment: The reason it's confusing is that when people say two polynomials or equal they are generally allowing the input to those polynomials to vary. So you aren't talking about polynomials, you're talking about polynomials *in $M$*, and then you still need to clarify that $M$ is fixed as opposed to itself a variable.

Comment: Thanks, @QiaochuYuan. I tried to clarify the problem using the terms you suggested. In fact, I now think that I should have dropped the polynomial formulation and only leave the reformulated problem, it is easier.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, perhaps it is already clear now, but just to complete the answer: M is fixed with characteristic polynomial $x^2-3x+1$, so $M^2-3M+M^0=0$. Thus, $3M^0 = 3M^0 + (M^2-3M+I)M^{-1} = M+M^{-1}$.